# Is it possible to update a submodule SHA without pulling?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo on local that has a reference to a submodule.
I would like to update the SHA referenced by the submodule to a more recent one.

The change is only to allow the CICD pipelines that run on the remote to pull in the latest submodule when building everything. I do not need, nor want, this submodule's contents locally.

Is there some way I can update the submodule's reference to a more recent SHA *without* pulling the submodule's contents from the remote?

Happy enough to even try editing git files to avoid pulling but I have not been able to find out where this reference is actually stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a core command to set index entries directly.

```
git update-index --cacheinfo 160000,<new_SHA_here>,path
```

sets the entry for `path` to that commit, exactly as if you'd `git add`ed a submodule's checkout of that commit.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Note to others that you need to use the *full* SHA, rather than the short SHA that git commands often accept. I imagine that this is because this is a core command and so doesn't reason about short SHA's, thus you need to be explicit.

Comment: Also, the repo doesn't have that object so it's got no way of finding the digits you don't tell it. Personally I think it'd be great if update-index would accept any revspec for the id.